# How do I use setInterval to dynamically change span.innerText

Tags: javascript, loops, state, intervals

I'm trying to dynamically re-render the span.innerText using the array , but for some reason the browser cannot read my state property, returning "cannot get property "text" of undefined".

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

```
    class Reja_S2_Staff extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: ["Zabawy", "Radości", "Smutku"]
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.changeSpan()
}

changeSpan =() => {

    let span = document.querySelector('#staff_span');


    for (let i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
        let interval = setInterval(function () {

            span.innerText = `${this.state.text[i]}`

        }, 2000);
    }

};


   render() {
    return (

        <div className='row' id='staff'>
            <div className='col-12'>

 <span id="staff_span" className="animate_span"> Zabawy </span>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
let _this = this;    

let interval = setInterval(function () {
   span.innerText = `${_this.state.text[i]}`
}, 2000);
```

Because the 'setInterval' function is scoped...

Comment: `changeSpan` is not inside the class, so the `this` keyword is not pointing to anything useful. It might work to simply add the function as a method of the class (and possibly avoid using arrow syntax -- I'm not sure how this affects things.)

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the anonymous function you pass to `setInterval` has a different meaning from this at the `setInterval` invocation level.

IMHO you can solve your problem rewriting `changeSpan` adding an explicit binding to *external `this`* as follows:

```
changeSpan =() => {

    let span = document.querySelector('#staff_span');
    const self = this;

    for (let i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
        let interval = setInterval(function () {
            span.innerText = `${self.state.text[i]}`
        }, 2000);
    }
};
```

or defining anonymous function passed to `setInterval` using a *lambda* (which should guarantee the `this` binding you expect):

```
changeSpan =() => {

    let span = document.querySelector('#staff_span');

    for (let i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
        let interval = setInterval( () => {
           span.innerText = `${this.state.text[i]}`
        }, 2000);
    }

};
```

I can't test these solutions at this moment, so I apologize in advance for typos and mistakes... Let me know if this can help you!

Comment: Hi @Wojciech Wojas, did my proposal help you? I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a Fiddle to explain the case:
[Fiddle with timeout and scope variable](https://jsfiddle.net/pg6uq9bv/10/).

There where also some other problems with the script:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
```

Changed to

```
let length = this.state.text.length - 1;

for (let i = 0; i <= length ; i++) {
```

Also, in this case it's better to use a timeout with a custom milliseconds setting/variable:

```
let timer = 2500 * i;

setTimeout( () => {
   span.innerText = self.state.text[i];
}, timer);
```

Hope the fiddle with help you on the right track...